# Identifying Friends

Tags: algorithm

> You are given an array containing information regarding n people. Each person is described using a string (their name) and a number (their position along a number
>   line). Each person has 3 friends, which are the 3 people whose number is nearest their own. Describe an algorithm to identify each person’s 3 friends.

Comment: Quite simply. No, we aren't doing your assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume this:

1 BOB , 2 Alice, 3 Ryan, 4 John, 5 Mike, 6 Jack, 7 Jane, 8 Rick, 9 Sam

Say, Bob's friends are Alice, Ryan and John. Alice's friends are Bob, Ryan and John. Ryan friends are Bob, Alice, John. So far everything seems fine. But when you go to John, his friends must either be Alice, Ryan and Mike, or Ryan, Mike and Jack. In both cases it is wrong because John is Bob's friend and there is NO WAY that Bob can be John's friend according to the question's condition.

It could be an assignment given to you by your professor but it either misses something or just wrong. It is not feasible UNLESS if you have 3 friends it is not conditional for them to have you as friend, making it okay that Bob has John as friend while John doesn't have Bob as friend and this makes another problem of HOW TO SELECT the friends, are they the previous 2 plus the next 1? or previous 1 plus the next 2? That's also not clear.

Revise the question.

Comment: It is Important to note  that friendship is not mutual here.  A is a friend of B does not implies B is also a friend of A. Also numbers are not necessarily continuous integer but they can be like 1,3,8,45

Comment: The question is not very clear as you posted it. Anyway, now it can be easily though of. You have to sort the array based on their numbers. After sorting it you make the first person in the sorted array friends with the next three. The last person will be friend with his previous three. For the rest of them, check the difference between your own number and the two neighbors:
1 3 8 45 46 100
So for 45, it checks with 8 and 46, selects 46 as friend, then checks with 8 and 100 and selects 8 then checks with 3 and 100 and selects 3.
I hope you got the point.